# VBA Export Sheets to Separate CSV Starting at Sheet 4 and beyond

Tags: vba, excel

as the title suggests, I'm trying to export sheets **(starting from the fourth sheet and beyond, this is a fixed value)** to separate CSV files. Ideally it would be right into a folder on the desktop containing each files. Below is the code I've been working with / trying to tweak-

```
Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xcsvFile As String
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    xWs.Copy
    xcsvFile = CurDir & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename: = xcsvFile, _
    FileFormat: = xlCSV, CreateBackup: = False
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the worksheets collection index.

```
Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()

    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xcsvFile As String, w as long
    For w=4 to ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count
        with ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(w)
            xcsvFile = CurDir & "\" & .Name & ".csv"
            .Copy
            with ActiveWorkbook
                .SaveAs Filename:=xcsvFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV
                .Close savechanges:=false
            end with
        end with
    Next w

end sub
```

Is CurDir appropriate here? ActiveWorkbook.Path may be another option.

Comment: This worked perfectly (as did the ActiveWorkbook.Path) - quick question, let's say each sheet is named XXXX and to the name I want to add the written out month + year, is there a way to do that during the exporting process?

Comment: try something like `xcsvFile = CurDir & "\" & .Name & format(date, "-mmmyyyy") & ".csv"`

Comment: CurDir can change if you perform some operation on another application (open a word file perhaps). ActiveWorkbook.Path won't change.

Comment: Also worked perfectly- you're the best! If you don't mind- one last question, is there a way to delete column D of each sheet before exporting?

Comment: `.worksheets(1).columns(4).entirecolumn.delete` immediately under `with ActiveWorkbook` and before `.SaveAs Filename...`